# In Rails, what is the best way to have a Model with conditionals based on whether or not a request has come via the API or the web front-end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, namespaces, models, api-design

We are in the progress of building/migrating new features into our web application.  We have a namespaced API (V1) that the mobile applications use to communicate with the app.

While we are in transition (we will launch the features for the web first), how can one differentiate between API requests and web requests, for purposes of bifurcating the logic in the shared model files?  We need the models to stay the same for the mobile apps, but be different for the new big web-based features.  Unfortunately code like

`request.format`

Isn't available in models.

Or is there a way to tell the API controllers to use different model files, and have separate models for some API vs. web app controllers?

Comment: The obvious thing to do is add an attribute `from_api` to the appropriate models and use that in your model-level logic.  You'd have to make sure to set `from_api = true` in all of the API controllers that create new objects.  But what happens if you create an object on the web, and then later edit it via the API - what is your business logic for that?  Any answers we give will be speculation without knowing what the business logic is.

Comment: One example is mailers.  In the mobile app/API the Cart model needs to call the mailer and pass a single object (user can only purchase one item at a time).  In the web app we have built out a shopping cart system, and the Cart model needs to pass in an array of items and let the mailer know it will be dealing with multiple items instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you should put as much code as possible within the model, however does this particular piece of code belong there?

It begs the question, because this seems to be 1) presentation oriented and 2) concern with the state/request.

It makes me believe that this code should actually reside within controllers.

> API controllers to use different model files

Ofc, just use a different model...

You've provided little information about what you're trying to achieve, which makes things difficult.

However, this seems like some presentation oriented code based of a web state.

There for, add decorators to your application and do your conditional presentation there.